# Jquery: Unable to get value of HTML 5 table loaded with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using MVC 5 to create an HTML5 database (with Bootstrap 3).  I loaded a table with JSON data and can see the data.  When  click on a link within a `<td>` I cannot get the spouseid (5056). My page inspector does indicate proper HTML syntax.

My table is:

```
<tr id="trSpouse">
<td id="tdSpouse">
<a class="spouseLink" href="#" data-spouseid="5056">John Doe</a>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

My jquery to get the first value is:

```
var spouseID = $(this).find('#tdSpouse').first('.spouseLink').text()
```

Obviously, this gives me 'John Doe' no matter which row I click

To get specific row values I tried

```
var spouseID = $(this).find('#tdSpouse').closest('.spouseLink').text()
```

which gives a blank value.

I've also tried:

```
var spouseID = $(this).find('#tdSpouse').first('.spouseLink').data('spouseid');
```

but I get 'undefined'

Can anyone help me with the Jquery to get the 'spouseid' value for the row I click?

Comment: you shouldn't use the same id. An ID - like the name says - should be a unique Identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the click event on `.spouseLink`:

```
$(".spouseLink").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('spouseid'));
});
```

Here's a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dRbC9/)

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know I could access the a click event directly.  I thought I had to find it through the table

Answer (score 0):

This happens because jQuery `.data()` just get data set by `.data(val)` function.

Your 'data-spouseid' write in html is not a jQuery data. It's just a HTML element attribute.

Then you will be able to get it value using:

```
var spouseID = $(this).find('#tdSpouse').first('.spouseLink').attr('data-spouseid');
```

Answer (score 0):

To have consistent behavior switch the `data()` call to an `attr()` call:

```
var spouseID = $(this).find('#tdSpouse').first('.spouseLink').attr('data-spouseid');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this as a click on the row anywhere:

```
$(this).find('.spouseLink').attr('data-spouseid');
```

if you are doing this as a click on the a

```
$(this).attr('data-spouseid');
```